# массив json преобразовать в javascript массив

Tags: javascript, json

Посредством php получаю такой массив

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Первый пункт"},{"id":"2","name":"Второй пункт"},{"id":"3","name":"Третий пункт"}]
```

как его можно распарсить в javascript, чтобы дальше с ним работать?

P.S. имею ввиду как к нему обратиться в итоге, потому что объявляю его в переменную.

```
var obj2=
obj2 = JSON.parse(obj2);
```

А теперь не могу понять как например обратиться к id 2 и вывести name

Comment: `$.parseJSON(json)`

Comment: Не могу понять в чём вопрос? Вроде готовый к употреблению массив. Не? Или какова конечная цель? Чего добиться надо?

Comment: let json = JSON.parse("[{...},{...}]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А теперь не могу понять как например обратиться к id 2 и вывести name

Для этой цели `JSON.parse` не нужен:

```js
let json = [{"id":"1","name":"Первый пункт"},{"id":"2","name":"Второй пункт"},{"id":"3","name":"Третий пункт"}];
let obj = json.find(x => x.id === '2');
if (!obj) {
  console.log('object with id = 2 not found');
} else {
  let name = obj.name;
  if (typeof name === "undefined")
    console.log('object with id = 2 not have "name"');
  else
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: А что если в `json` не найдется объекта с `id` строго равным `'2'`, каков будет результат выполнения?

Comment: @yar85 тогда будет возвращаться ошибка `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Чтобы избежать ошибки, Вы можете проверять сначала `json.find(x => x.id === '2')` на `undefined`, после чего получать `name`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91631/discussion-on-answer-by-alex--json---javascript-).

Answer (score 0):

Метод `JSON.parse()` при успешном выполнении возвращает JS-объект (экземпляр Object или Array).
В данном случае, результатом будет Array, а если конкретнее - массив объектов:

```
const jsonStr = '[{"id":"1","name":"Первый пункт"},{"id":"2","name":"Второй пункт"},{"id":"3","name":"Третий пункт"}]'; 
let arr = JSON.parse(jsonStr);   // [[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]]
```

Обращаться с этим массивом можно точно так же, как и с любым другим:

```
// доступ к элементу по его индексу 
let firstEntry = arr[0];       // [object Object] { id: "1", name: "Первый пункт" }
console.log(firstEntry.name);  // "Первый пункт"

// поиск элемента перебирающим методом
let entry = arr.find(obj => obj.id == 2); 
if (entry)
  console.log(entry.name); 
else
  console.log('Объект с id:2 в массиве не найден');
```

Comment: @Alex, будь добр, сформулируй вопрос без провокаций некорректными формулировками (вида "ты забыл, что ...", "почему не читаешь", "взял мой ответ", и т.д.) Один раз я тебе ответил в той же манере, но не собираюсь и далее вести такие разговоры. Не желаешь ли пожелать себе быть немного дружелюбнее, и вести конструктивный диалог **по теме и содержанию ответов**, вместо перехода на личности и оценок вымышленных действий? (последний вопрос - риторический)

Comment: Начать можно с изложения упомянутой логики, в том виде как ты ее понял - чтобы цепочка твоих рассуждений была ясна. А то ранее я написал что есть разница между ошибками входных данных, и ошибками программиста (алгоритмическими), но не видно чтобы в твоем вопросе это как-то учитывалось - вероятно, я неправильно его (твой вопрос) понимаю => давай проясним.

Comment: @Alex, допустим, твой вопрос задан без эмоций и "правильно" - но он **некорректен**. По остальному: было написано что ошибка **алгоритмическая** (от слова "алгоритм"), а не "арифметическая". Также, напомню, что мы тут на SO занимаемся созданием базы ответов на вопросы общего характера, а не услугами написания кода под какие-то конкретные данные каких-то конкретных людей. Поэтому, ответы должны быть качественными. Своим комментом я указал на проблему качества твоего ответа, для его улучшения - и столкнувшись с неадекватной реакцией, написал свой вариант ответа (учитывающий поправку). Это ясно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91615/discussion-between-alex-and-yar85).